# SQL restore transaction log from disk getting incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

The command I am using  is below and i'm getting incorrect syntax near 'E:'  What am I misisng or what do I have wrong?  Thanks for the help everybody!

```
restore log ib_qc FROM DISK 'e:\backup_201202030600.trn' WITH NORECOVERY
```

Comment: Maybe E: is a network drive and you (sql service) do not have the necessary rights to it...

Comment: Maybe you need to escape the \ with \\?

Comment: or try a full UNC path - it works 100% :)

Comment: Pretty sure @Icarus is right with this one, \b is backspace....

Comment: @Icarus - The only thing that needs escaping in TSQL string literals is single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

```
restore log ib_qc FROM DISK = 'e:\backup_201202030600.trn' WITH NORECOVERY
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175093.aspx